# Save VPN password for all users using nmcli

Tags: networking, network-manager, password, vpn, openvpn

Is it possible to save a VPN password using nmcli and make it available to all users?

`nmcli con modify vpnname vpn.secrets "password=mypassword"` does the job, but only for current user.

The only way I found so far is by modifying this setting through the graphic interface, in the "Identity" tab of the VPN connection:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.01.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same result without going through the GUI, you can manually add a section in the configuration file of that VPN connection:

*/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vpn_connection_name_*

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=password
```